# Problem with GIMP, it doesn't show correct image as in compair with Photoshop!

Tags: gimp, xubuntu

I have GIMP 2.8.2 on my Ubuntu 12.10 machine.
Graphic designer claims PSD file is like this:

[image]
[image]

However, when I open it with my GIMP, its like this:

[image]
[image]

I have no idea what is the problem.
Any advice/comment would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, GIMP is not 100% compatible with PSD-files since it does not support all features of Photoshop. It especially does not support layer style (I think that is why the Facebook-button is black). See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=825934) or [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1786229) forum thread for more information.